# Text Pattern Overlay

Tags: html, css, background, overlay, background-image

I would like to overlay a text with pattern.

current text:
[image]

desired result:
[image]

Here is what I tried:

```
<p style="background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QixlA.jpg);>International experiance</p>
```

Direct link to pattern picture:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/QixlA.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, exactly how you wanted it: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CHUrB/304/)

```
<p class="bnd">International experiance</p>

.bnd 
{
    font-size: 48px;   
    font-weight: bold;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/kODqYvS.jpg);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abdulmalik/VUC5W/)

```
h1{color: white;  /* Fallback: assume this color ON TOP of image */
   background: url(http://i.imgur.com/kODqYvS.jpg) ;
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;}
```